# Replacing a failed drive in DRBD ()

Tags: disk, drbd

How to correctly set the size of the disk,  when replacing, if I want to use the original disk size?

The volume of the new disk is 4 Gb, but I want to use only the volume that was used before and is used on the disk of another node (2 Gb).

Resource:

```
resource res-vdb {

  device drbd_res_vdb1 minor 1;
  disk /dev/vdb;   
  meta-disk internal;

  protocol C;

  on node01 {
    address 192.168.0.1:7005;
  }

  on node02 {
    address 192.168.0.2:7005;
  }
}
```

Do I understand correctly that I can take the size from lsblck or from /sys/block/drbd1/size and set in res config before drbdadm create-md and drbdadm attach?

i.e. config:

```
resource res-vdb {

  device drbd_res_vdb1 minor 1;
  disk /dev/vdb;   
  meta-disk internal;

  protocol C;

  disk {
        size 2097052K;      <==== 2GB
    }
  on node01 {
    address 192.168.0.1:7005;
  }

  on node02 {
    address 192.168.0.2:7005;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that you can set the size in the DRBD res file before you `create-md` and `attach` in order to explicitly set the size of the DRBD device.

As you've also suggested, you can retrieve the exact size of the DRBD device in various ways, including using `lsblk` or inspecting the kernel settings with `cat /sys/block/drbd1/size`, run from the peer node.

However, when you use `lsblk`, it's going to do some rounding. DRBD's parser doesn't seem to accept bytes (`B`) as a valid unit (with `drbd-utils` version 9.13.1 seems to only like `KB`, `MB`, and `GB`), so you might be better off setting the size in sectors (`s`).

The size you find in `/sys/block/drbd1/size` is already in sectors, so an example would be:

```
# cat /sys/block/drbd1/size 
27262072

# cat /etc/drbd.d/r1.res 
resource res-vdb {
    protocol C;
    disk /dev/vdb;
    device minor 1;
    disk {
        size 27262072s;
    }
    on centos7-a {
        address 172.16.7.100:7779;
    }
    on centos7-b {
        address 172.16.7.101:7779;
    }
}
```

All that said, because DRBD auto-negotiates the device size among it's peers, you could simply, `drbdadm create-md res-vdb`, `drbdadm up res-vdb`, and it should just work.